# Blocking Queue, Single Producer - Multiple Consumer Synchronization issues

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, queue

I want to confirm before going my code to production.

I am using LinkedBlockingQueue like shown below.
I have one producer thread and five consumer thread.
Consumer thread does DB operation, So I have increased it to 5 to fasten the process.

Now, is there any way I will run into (Synchronization/Multiple updates for row/or any issue which I need to take care) problem either at Code or DB level.

Below is my complete code.

```
private int numberOfConsumers = 5;
private LinkedBlockingQueue<RequestParameters> processorQueue;


public void init(){
        processorQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<RequestParameters>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfConsumers ; i++) {
            try {
                QueueConsumer c = new QueueConsumer(processorQueue);
                c.setName("ThreadName-"+i);
                c.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("", e);
            }
        }
        this.postCallProcessorDaemon = this;
    }



    class QueueConsumer extends Thread {
        private  Logger log = Logger.getLogger(QueueConsumer.class);
        private final BlockingQueue<RequestParameters> queue;
        QueueConsumer(BlockingQueue<RequestParameters> q) { queue = q; }

      public void run() {   
            try {
                while (true) {
                    RequestParameters rp = queue.take();
                    consumeRecord(rp);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Exception in run method", ex);
            }
        }


    void consumeRecord(RequestParameters requestParameters) 
    {
    try{
           process(requestParameters);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error("Exception",e);
        }
    }


    private void process(RequestParameters requestParameters) throws Exception{
        for (Action each : allActions) {
            if(each.doProcessing(requestParameters)){
                boolean status = each.process(requestParameters);
            }
        }
    }

}


public boolean process(RequestParameters parameters) {
   //In my process method, I am inserting rows in table based on data in Queue.
}
```

HBM file which I am using for ORM mapping

```
<class name="CampaignSubscriptionsSummary" table="campaign_subscriptions_summary">
    <composite-id name="id" class="com.on.robd.config.db.reports.CampaignSubscriptionsSummaryId">
        <key-property name="reportTime" type="timestamp">
            <column name="REPORT_TIME" length="19" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="campaignId" type="long">
            <column name="CAMPAIGN_ID" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="recipient" type="string">
            <column name="RECIPIENT" length="24" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="selectedPack" type="string">
            <column name="SELECTED_PACK" length="256" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="campaign" class="com.on.robd.config.db.campaigns.Campaign" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="CAMPAIGN_ID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="campaignSubscriptionsStatusDim" class="com.on.robd.config.db.reports.CampaignSubscriptionStatusDim" fetch="select">
        <column name="SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS_ID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="sender" type="string">
        <column name="SENDER" length="24" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="callDuration" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="CALL_DURATION" />
    </property>
    <property name="dtmfInput" type="string">
        <column name="DTMF_INPUT" length="16" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="promptForPack" type="string">
        <column name="PROMPT_FOR_PACK" length="256" />
    </property>
    <property name="wavFile" type="string">
        <column name="WAV_FILE" length="256" />
    </property>
    <property name="subscriptionUrl" type="string">
        <column name="SUBSCRIPTION_URL" length="256" />
    </property>
    <property name="language" type="string">
        <column name="LANGUAGE" length="256" />
    </property>
    <property name="reobdTime" type="timestamp">
            <column name="REOBD_TIME" length="19" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="campaignTypeDim" class="com.on.robd.config.db.reports.CampaignTypeDim" fetch="select">
        <column name="CAMPAIGN_TYPE_ID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but it should be the other way. There should be single person who should be operating on the database and many other people can ask for database operation.

Comment: I went for multiple Consumer because I want to make sure that when I get an entry in Queue then that will get processed soon other then single consumer do that task and an entry at last in Queue has to wait long for processing as my Producer is very fast and consumer is slow. If I go for your approach then things will again slow down.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you'll have DB locking issues between the consumers, but it depends on your database vendor.  Check your DB vendors docs to see if it uses table, row or partition locking on write.

But Regardless you'll get better write performance is you use batch inserting.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html .  The simplest way to batch, would be to have your Producer push a collection of RequestParameters into your BlockingQueue.  This could also reduce the number of open connections you have to the DB which will also help with performance.

Comment: Do you imply opening a DB connection and then caching it and use it each time an item is taken from the queue?